# Setting label in DendrogramPlot

Tags: visualization, time-series, cluster-analysis

I want to create a dendrogram with the labels being a visual representation of the data. Something like this:
[image: What I wanna do]

How can I do that in *Mathematica*? My attempt so far hasn't been very successful. The labels are all messed up.

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]
SeedRandom@2;
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10, 20}];
label = ListPlot[#, Axes -> False, Joined -> True] & /@ data;
DendrogramPlot[data, Orientation -> Right, LeafLabels -> label]
```

This is what I get from the code above:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Straightforward approach with controlling related heights.

```
Needs["HierarchicalClustering`"]
SeedRandom@2;
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {10, 20}];

height = 50;
label = ListPlot[#, Axes -> False, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> {300, height}, 
                    AspectRatio -> height/300] & /@ data;
```

**Edit** I'm sorry my previous version has not included correct order of the samples.

```
With[{h = Length[data] height, 
      plot = Reap@DendrogramPlot[data, LeafLabels -> (Sow@Position[data, #][[1, 1]] &),  
                                       Orientation -> Right]
     },
 Row[{
      Column[label[[plot[[2, 1]]]], Spacings -> 0],
      Show[plot[[1]], ImageSize->{300, h},  AspectRatio -> h/300, 
                      ImagePadding -> {{10, 0}, {height/2, height/2}}]
 }]]
```

[image]